# リストの値からネストへアクセスする方法

Tags: python

```
A = [[a,b,c],
     [d,e,f],
     [g,h,i]]
```

入れ子になっているリストのどれか一つにアクセスしたとして、
そこから全体のネストを取得することはできますか？
例えば、a~iが全部あるクラスのインスタンスであるとし、ある一つの
インスタンスで作業を行っているとします。その
インスタンスに変更が加えられたとき、全体のインスタンスに
その変更を伝える時、変更が加えられたインスタンスが属する
ネストを取得したいと考えています。
もちろん、変数Aという名前に入っているという情報でも
OKです。変数名を値の方から取得するという事が
できるかという問題にもなるかもしれません。

ふつうは、変数Aを取り、それからリスト内のインスタンスへ、という
形が流れだと思いますが、逆の流れで、中のインスタンスから外の変数
へ、という流れができるかをお聞きしたいです。

Comment: 「全体のネスト」の意味がちょっとはっきりわからないのですが， `A` と `b` を与えられたときに `[a,b,c]` がほしいというようなことでしょうか？

Comment: いえ、[a,b,c]だけでなく、全体です。わけあって、面倒な処理をしていたので楽にならないかなと思ったんですが、どうやらなかったみたいですね。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

できません。
そういうことをしたい場合はその要素の中にリストの位置情報、あるいは上位ネストの位置情報を入れるようにすることですね